# Does it matter that my QEMU domain's disk is not part of a pool / volume, and if so, how to safely correct it?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, libvirt

I've read some of the documentation from Libvert, Red Hat, etc. but I'm a bit overwhelmed by it all and I don't think I grasp the overall purpose of pools and volumes for QEMU virtual machines.

I have two domains that I created in QEMU, without really knowing what I was doing. The primary disks of each are configured almost identically, here's an example of the XML:

```
<disk type="file" device="disk">
  <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>
  <source file="/home/brian/kvmpool/ubuntu1.qcow2" index="1"/>
  <backingStore/>
  <target dev="vda" bus="virtio"/>
  <alias name="virtio-disk0"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x04" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</disk>
```

In the pool `default` there is a volume that corresponds to `unbuntu1.qcow2`. My other domain has an image file in another folder, let's say `/home/brian/ubuntu2.qcow2` and there is no volume in any pool that corresponds to this image.

Is this bad? Do pools and volumes just exist in QEMU for convenience or do they serve another purpose? Should I move `ubuntu2.qcow2` to a volume, and if so, how? Or if that's not necessary, could I safely delete the volume that contains without `unbuntu1.qcow2` impacting the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question after some more digging. The following is [from libvirt documentation](https://libvirt.org/storage.html).

> **Storage pools and volumes are not required for the proper operation of VMs.** Pools and volumes provide a way for libvirt to ensure that a
> particular piece of storage will be available for a VM, but some
> administrators will prefer to manage their own storage and VMs will
> operate properly without any pools or volumes defined. On systems that
> do not use pools, system administrators must ensure the availability
> of the VMs' storage using whatever tools they prefer, for example,
> adding the NFS share to the host's fstab so that the share is mounted
> at boot time.